# Executing function only once 

Tags: jquery

I have a register form where visitors can sign up, and when they press the submit button the div containing the register form is being moved slightly to left so that it appears in the middle.

The code doing that works fine, but if the visitor has wrote something wrong in the register form they need to be able to try again, but then the register form will be moved once again, if this is repeated a few times it will move out of the container totally.

How can I trigger a function only once? Here is my current code:

```
...

$('#form form').submit(function(){

// Some code for showing "loading" image etc..

});
```

Comment: I think instead of running submit function once (Which will cause problem for users who already submit wrong information once), you need to have another handler for users who had issue in registration to move the form back to where it was.

Comment: @Qorbani yeah, that could have been one solution as well, but I wanted to have a register form like the one at [Academia](http://academia.edu), check it out, looks very cool, according to me ;).

Comment: thanks for sharing link :-) Another way to achieve this is by using CSS tricks and adding CSS class to your form container, to move your form and then in submit logic you only add class to form and even if it was there, it will not apply effect twice. The other benefit it separating user interface logic of off your code.

Comment: Good idea, but what about IE and such? Using CSS tricks would have a lot of benefits like you mentioned, but will it not be harder to achieve these effects with pure css? Maybe hard to tell, but would be interesting to know until next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) call,

```
$('#form form').one('submit', function(){

// Some code for showing "loading" image etc..

});
```

Then it will only be fired the first time.